# Purchase of product automatically handled with automatic mail?

Tags: product, extensions, email, downloadable

I will try to be as specific as I can be.

I have a Magento webstore, now I wanted to know, if it is possible when a customer purchases a product, (ie: a license) that said product would be handled automatically, and that the customer will get his license (code or key) delivered by mail automatically without human interference.

Is there a way to make this work? Installing a bot, or a plug-in?

Hopefully one of you can help me out on this!

Comment: Order success email..! Are you talking about the same?

Comment: No, i actually meant this:  A customer orders let's say a antivirus license software key, the whole process goes automatically, the customer eventually gets the key automatically delivered to his mail

Answer (score 0):

You could follow this way:

Use an observer to add custom option & it's value programmatically.
In Your case Custom option

```
Title: License Key
Value: xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx
```

Now default magento by default send the custom option details in order success email.

Comment: i'm not sure (and this is just a wild guess, so correct me if i'm wrong) that the observer could be programmed to function on one or maybe two specific products, is it possible for the observer that to act on a specific product if a customer buys that certain specific product he or she will get the key in their mail?

Comment: To make products specific you can add one attribute as "License Key Type" & it's value as "yes/no". based on this attribute value you could generate the license key as custom option. :)